# Implement real time notification(message) feature in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, redis

I need to implement real time notification feature in my rails app. Can anybody tell me what are possible good ways to implement this feature?

One of my colleague suggested me to go with node.js and redis. Is it the right way to proceed for this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/).  Do not bother with Node.js.

Comment: Does this support for mobile brower aswell ?

Comment: I believe this depends more on capabilities of mobile browser.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Private Pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub).  It's a Ruby gem that makes use of a publish/subscribe system called [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/).

You set up client-side message handlers in Javascript that listen to particular channels.  Then, from the Rails side of things, you can publish messages to those channels.  The messages are picked up  effectively in "real time" back on the client side.

It's been working wonderfully for me; I'd strongly suggest anyone giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For real time notifications try [Pusher](http://pusher.com/).

If you get any notifications like a `new message` then you can go on to setup a handler at client side. Likewise on the server side, you can tell pusher to `notify` for a message to any client that you want typically the one that sends the notifications.

Comment: great, thanks Saurabh this can be suitable solution for my current problem, but this is paid service.

Comment: yes you can try it if you really want good one. There are nice documentations also on site so no problems in setting up:)